# How can Flutter get the SSID of WIFI in Android 12 or 13？

Tags: flutter

I use network_info_plus plug -in to obtain WIFI information. The models of the 12th -pm can be obtained. The SSID obtained by the 12 and above models is NULL. Please help me tell me how to solve this problem.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

```
Future<void> setNetwork() async {
final info = NetworkInfo();
var locationStatus = await Permission.location.status;
if (locationStatus.isDenied) {
  await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
}
if (await Permission.location.isRestricted) {
  openAppSettings();
}

if (await Permission.location.isGranted) {
  var wifiName = await info.getWifiName();
  log('wifiName $wifiName');
  }
}
```

What method needs to be implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus) package to get all the network info wi-fi-related information.

just install it with

```
flutter pub add network_info_plus
```

And use below code snippet to get SSID

```
var wifiBSSID = await info.getWifiBSSID(); // 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is very helpful for me.
I have checked it due to the problem caused by the software installation process. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the main problem of iOS operation, you need to use a Provisioning Profile that has these capabilities:
Access WiFi information
Hotspots